# If $f(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n) = \min_i\{\lambda_i\}$, then $\frac{d}{d\lambda_i}f > 0?$

Tags: calculus

Let $\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}$ a collection of numbers. If $f(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n) = \min_i\{\lambda_i\}$, then $\frac{d}{d\lambda_i}f > 0?$

Note that if $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$, then

$$f(\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = \frac{1}{2}(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 - |\lambda_1-\lambda_2|).$$ Therefore,

$$\frac{d}{d\lambda_1}f(\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2|-\lambda_1+\lambda_2|} > 0.$$

The same holds for $\frac{d}{d\lambda_2}f$.

Does this hold when I pass from $2$ to $n$? I guess it is true and can be shown via induction. Is this right?

Comment: Something here seems odd, If I take for example $\min(0,x)$, then it isn't differentiable at $0$, so I think the answer is no..

Comment: I am assuming: only differentiability where $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$.

Comment: If so, then isn't it guranteed that there's a neighborhood in which the function acts like some $\lambda_j$? Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda_i} = 0$ unless $i=j$, in which case it's $1$.

Comment: @Theorem, I think this is not true.

Comment: If you want to exclude diagonals, i.e. locus of points where $\lambda_i=\lambda_j$ for some $i\neq j$, then domain of $f$ is as follows. Let $\pi$ be a permutation of $\{1,2,\cdots, n\}$. Define
$
\Lambda(\pi)=\{(\lambda_{\pi(1)}, \cdots, \lambda_{\pi(n)})\mid \lambda_1<\lambda_2<\cdots<\lambda_{n}\}$. Then your domain is the disjoint union $\bigcup_{\pi}\Lambda(\pi)$. Moreover $f|_{\Lambda(\pi)}(x_1,\cdots, x_n)=x_{\pi^{-1}(1)}$. So $\partial f|_{\Lambda(\pi)}/\partial x_j=0$ unless $j=\pi^{-1}(1)$, in which case this partial is equal to one.

Comment: @Hamed, please, consider post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Don't worry about it, as long as you're happy ;)

Comment: @Hamed I am sure that L.F. Cavenaghi is happy, but it would be nice that it is visible *at first glance* in the list of questions that it is answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude diagonals, i.e. locus of points where $\lambda_i=\lambda_j$ for some $i\neq j$, then domain of $f$ is as follows. Let $\pi$ be a permutation of $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$. Define 
$$\Lambda(\pi)=\{(\lambda_{\pi(1)},\cdots,\lambda_{\pi(n)})\mid \lambda_1<\lambda_2<\cdots <\lambda_n\}$$ Then your domain is the disjoint union $\bigcup_\pi \Lambda(\pi)$.

Moreover $f\mid_{\Lambda(\pi)}(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=x_{π^{−1}(1)}$. So $\partial f\mid_{\Lambda(\pi)}/\partial x_j=0$ unless $j=\pi^{−1}(1)$, in which case this partial is equal to one.

Comment: +1 for the answer.